# Bagging with decision stumps in sklearn: how to view the results?

Tags: scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I'm using the BaggingClassifier with a depth-1 decision tree to try to split up my data into subsets where the classifier might be better. How do I view the data subsets that were selected by the Bagging procedure? Here is the run line I'm using:

```
clf = BaggingClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1),n_estimators=2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you might have known, *BaggingClassifier* may randomize subsets via randomizing features and/or randomizing samples from the train data.

Imagine I have 36 samples and 2 features stored in **X** variable and 36 target binary samples stored in **y** variable. I try to deal with the problem of classification as you do via *BaggingClassifier*.

```
clf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1),
                        n_etimators=1)  # for simplicity
clf.fit(X, y)
```

It will return the following:

```
BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=1,
        max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
        min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
        min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
        presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best'),
        bootstrap=True, bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0,
        max_samples=1.0, n_estimators=1, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False,
        random_state=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

As **sklearn** documentation states, the crucial parameters for subsetting data are both *max_samples* and *max_features*, the parameters for randomization are *bootstrap* and *bootstrap_features*.

The first two parameters, if defined as floats ranged from 0. to 1., are the proportions of the samples and features of **X** transmitted to the base_estimator (in your case it is DecisitonTreeClassifier).

The second two parameters serve as a randomization factor (or dropping out factor) of both samples and features obtained by the first two parameters above. By default, *bootstrap* is True which means that it randomly chooses samples from the predefined proportion in *max_samples*. I have provided an example in the end to let you understand the process.

So, by default your classifier gets every sample and every feature from your **X** and drops out samples only (because you have not changed the parameters in the classifier). After you have fitted your classifier you may check what features were choses by typing `clf.estimators_features_`. For me, it prints two features from **X** data fitted by 1 DecisionTreeClassifier and not by 2000 as I have stated in *n_estimators* for simplicity:

> [array([0, 1])]
>
> As you can see, it chose every feature because max_features is 1. and bootstrap_features is False

Okay, so what are the samples transmitted to that DecisionTreeClassifier? You can verify that by typing `clf.estimators_samples_` that will return something like this:

> [array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,
>           True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,
>           True, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False,
>          False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)]

You see, it is a boolean mask of transmitted samples from **X** during the fit of DecisionTreeClassifer in BaggingClassifier. If you had *n_estimators* equal to 2000, you would have 2000 arrays with randomized samples as long as *bootstrap* set True.

Finally, how to actually see what samples were chosen? In other words, how to convert that boolean mask? The code is below:

```
mask = np.array(clf.estimators_samples_).ravel()
X[mask, :]
```

That is it! Note that if you had 2000 estimators and you wanted to check what samples were chosen to fit, say, 1000th DecisionTreeClassifier, you would type something like that:

```
mask = np.array(clf.estimators_samples_[999].ravel()
X[mask, :]
```

The code `X[mask, :]` chooses only those samples (rows of NumPy array) that satisfy the True condition in the *mask* variable. If you apriori have Pandas DataFrame, you alter `X[mask, :]` to `X.ix[mask, :]`. I hope that is clear for you now! Thank you!

E.

P.S.

> The example showing how *bootstrap* works

```
clf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1), n_estimators=1, bootstrap=True)
clf.fit(np.array(x.values),np.array(Y.values))
clf.estimators_samples_
```

> [array([ True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,
>           True,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True, False,
>          False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,
>          False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)]
>
> Some of them were dropped out

```
clf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1), n_estimators=1, bootstrap=False)
clf.fit(np.array(x.values),np.array(Y.values))
clf.estimators_samples_
```

> [array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
>           True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
>           True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
>           True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)]
>
> All of them were chosen

So, as you can see, you can vary the samples and features proportionally or by dropping some of them out.